# CSS 100vh offset by header

Tags: html, css, flexbox, viewport-units

I have this pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPdrod

As you can see (at least in Chrome and Firefox), there are 2 vertical scroll bars. There should only be the inner one, as the header should remain static.

The CSS causing this is:

```
#app
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Particularly the 100vh height. This is causing the viewport to be too tall by 36px. Which is the header height. If I do:

```
#app
{
    ...
    height: calc(100vh - 36px);
}
```

Then it works perfectly fine. I'm trying to figure out why I need to do this in the first place. What about this layout is causing the 100vh to account for the header height? I feel like I shouldn't have to do that calc as the header is within the layout div along with the rest of the elements.

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a codepen which can disappear tomorrow and make your question and the answers useless. [mcve]

Comment: I updated my answer a little, tried to make it more clear. Let me know if there is something else I can clarify or adjust.

Comment: As I didn't get any response I simply assume my answer didn't help, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

`#header` is inside `#app` so it's normal behavior, specially if your neighbor (`#body`) has `height: 100%` (height is set relative to parent so it's also `100vh`). That's the reason to show second scroll.

What actually you can do is removing height from `#body`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If I take the height off of body, then the header scrolls off the screen. The header needs to stay static at the top. The content area should have the scrollbar.

Comment: @Troncoso add `position:fixed` in #header

Comment: You can try also with height: calc(100% - 36px) in #body.